# StreamSocketListener ConnectionReceived and COMException

Tags: c#, thread-safety, listener, uwp, comexception

I have a listener and it works fine except moment when events are too frequently. In this case COMException "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" it thrown on line

```
resp.FlushAsync()
```

and it coudn't be catched with try-catch. As I understand it is because process is going in separate thread.

Here is simplified example:

```
 private readonly StreamSocketListener listener;

    // ... somewhere initialization
        this.listener = new StreamSocketListener();
        this.listener.ConnectionReceived += (s, e) => ProcessRequestAsync(e.Socket);
        this.listener.BindServiceNameAsync("8080");
    }

   // ... and event
    private async void ProcessRequestAsync(StreamSocket socket)
    {
        StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();
        using (IInputStream input = socket.InputStream)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[8192];
            IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
            uint dataRead = 8192;
            while (dataRead == 8192)
            {
                await input.ReadAsync(buffer, 8192, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
                request.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, data.Length));
                dataRead = buffer.Length;
            }
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        using (IOutputStream output = socket.OutputStream)
        {
            using (Stream resp = output.AsStreamForWrite())
            {
                byte[] headerArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n" +
                                         "Content-Length:0\r\n" +
                                         "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
                await resp.WriteAsync(headerArray, 0, headerArray.Length);

                await resp.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

What I have tried to do:
1. using semaphoreSlim
2. catch (COMException)
3. add this.listener.Control.KeepAlive = false; // or also true
4. add application unhandled exception

Any ideas? ManualResetEvent?

Comment: You can catch the exception [within](http://www.axilis.com/2015/07/27/async-exception-handling-in-c/) your exception handler.

Comment: I have tried this and it's not caught. That's a problem. Probably because it's COM exception and it runs not in main thread.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `FlushAsync` call? It is only needed in certain situations. Also, why the delay for 1 second?

Comment: Thank you, @PeterTorr-MSFT. Without FlushAsync it works much more better. Almost like a charm! But only sometimes I still get COMException on line 
    `await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);` Delay for 1 second is just to show that some taking time operation is at this place of code.

Comment: Can't mark this question as answered,  but yes, FlushAsync() is the answer.